# Application crash while adding images to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to add Image and text on UICollectionViewCell.
So I used this code

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSString *cellData = [firstSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.titleLabel setText:cellData];

    NSString *imageName = [second objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"CV setting image for row %ld from file in bundle with name '%@'", (long)indexPath.row, imageName);

    cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    return cell;

}
```

FirstSection array have some name and Second array have images. Text displayed but images are not working.

So Please tell me whats wrong in my code.

I got errors like this:

```
2014-11-07 15:18:56.928 CollectionViewExample[4459:151457] CV setting image for row 0 from file in bundle with name '(
    "real_estate_2.png",
    "photography_2.png",
    "auto_2.png",
    "electronics_2.png",
    "services_2.png"
)'
2014-11-07 15:18:56.929 CollectionViewExample[4459:151457] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be86240

2014-11-07 15:18:57.044 CollectionViewExample[4459:151457] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be86240'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02bf5df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01975a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02bfda75 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02b469c7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02b4658e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x008ad0be +[_UIAssetManager createAssetNamed:fromBundle:] + 66
    6
```

Comment: There is issue of IBOutlet in your collectionview custom cell. Please check it once

Comment: Log your arrays and make sure the elements in it are strings. They seem to be arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The most common mistake I often did in UICollectionView was due to not writing

> [self.myCollectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class]
>   forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MYCELL"];

Have you tried providing a static image in your imageView? If it works, then I presume your UIImage from array might need typecasting

Follow this link : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_iOS_6_Collection_View_and_Flow_Layout

Comment: @PavanAlapati This looks like it might be your solution, as the unrecognised selector error is being thrown for `UICollectionViewCell`, not `myCellCollectionViewCell`. Note that at the moment you are getting the cell registered for "cellIdentifier".

Comment: NO need to register cell if you are using storyboards

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is your new, or older `collectionViewCell` not having a property called (`imageView` before) or `myImageOnCollectionView` now. It´s for that your collection view does not respond to selector. (Selector is the same than methods).
If you have a custom `collectionCell` (easy approach) in its implementation file(.h) add this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *theNameYouWant; // The must be the same you implement en cellForRow...
```

// Connect this property with the storyboard representation. (Be sure in storyBoard the cell must be your own cell class).

When you connect `IBOutlet` appear;

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *theNameYouWant;
```

// if you have all in code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for easy answer but it see like

imageName it's NSArray not NSString

```
cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:<NSArray>];
```

Please NSLog(@"%@", second);